# Select onchange calls method with value depending on option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This following method is already called from multiple different places so I wouldn't like to change signature.

```
doSomething(json){
  ...
}
```

Now I also need to call this method each time a new option is selected from a select field. Each option has some specific json to that option. I need to achieve something like this:

```
<select onchange="doSomething(json)">
  <option value="1" json="{'key': 'json1'}">name 1</option>
  <option value="2" json="{'key': 'json2'}">name 2</option>
</select>
```

How can I get the `json` attribute of `selected` option to the method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you to use custom [`data-*`attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) to persist arbitrary information which can be retrived later by using [`.data(key)`](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data2)

As you don't want to modify the `doSomething` method, attach another click handler. You can target the option using [`:selected` selector](https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/)

```js
$('#yourSelect').on('change', function() {
  //Retrieve data
  var json = $(this).find(':selected').data('json');
  //call the method 
  doSomething(json); 
}).change();

function doSomething(json) {
  console.clear();
  console.log(json);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="yourSelect">
  <option value="1" data-json='{"key": "json1"}'>name 1</option>
  <option value="2" data-json='{"key": "json2"}'>name 2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Any code run from the `onchange=""` handler has `this` set to the element it's an attribute of, namely the `select` element. Therefore the following code works:

```html
<select onchange="alert(this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('json'))">
  <option value="1" json="{'key': 'json1'}">name 1</option>
  <option value="2" json="{'key': 'json2'}">name 2</option>
</select>
```

As another poster said, it is recommended to prepend such attribute names with `data-`:

[data-* - HTML | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*)